# Нахождение общих точек интервалов

Tags: java

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу. Первый человек ехал в промежутках (1,5), (8,10) а второй в промежутке (1,9). Найти промежутки когда они ехали вместе.
Результат будет (1,5), (8,9). Как можно реализовать эту задачу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю лучший ли вариант, но для решения "в лоб" сгодится:

1. Сортируем массивы промежутков (для первого и
       второго человека) по возрастанию
       начала промежутка. Если несколько
       промежутков совпадают - по
       возрастанию конца промежутков.
       *можно не сортировать - тогда вообще брутфорс получается:)
2. Два цикла - первый по промежуткам первого человека, второй - по
       второму. Сравниваем промежутки,
       заносим получившийся общий в третий
       массив.
3. Для красоты - сортируем 3й массив.

**UPD** код на яваскрипте (дополнил парой промежутков)

**UPD2** исправлен косяк с сортировкой, остался косяк с дублированием отрезков

```
// сортировка промежутков по-возрастанию начала промежутка (Selection sort)
function sortIntervals(interval_arr){ 
  var result = [];   
  for(var i=0;i<=interval_arr.length-1; i++){ 
    var insert_index = 0;
    // search position 
    for(var j=0; j<=result.length-1; j++){
      if(interval_arr[i][0] >= result[j][0]){        
        insert_index = j+1;
        // sort by interval length desc!
        for(var k=j+1; k<=result.length-1;k++){
          if(interval_arr[i][0] != result[k][0] )
            break;
          if(interval_arr[i][1] >= result[k][1]){   
            insert_index = k;
            break;
          }
        }
        break;
      }
    }    
    // insert
    result.splice(insert_index,0,interval_arr[i]);
  }   
  return result; 
}

// получение пересечения двух областей
function getCross(interval1, interval2){   
  // берем самую позднюю точку начала из двух
  var from = (interval1[0]>interval2[0])?interval1[0]:interval2[0];
  // берем самую раннюю точку конца
  var to = (interval1[1]<interval2[1])?interval1[1]:interval2[1];
  return (to>from)?[from, to]:null; 
}

// код программы
var man1 = [   [1,5], [11,15], [8,10], [8,11] ];
var man2 = [   [14,15], [1,9] ];

man1 = sortIntervals(man1); 
man2 = sortIntervals(man2);

var manCross = []; // result 
for(var i=0;i<=man1.length-1; i++){   
  for(var j=0; j<=man2.length-1; j++){
    var cross = getCross(man1[i], man2[j]);
    if(cross)
      manCross.push(cross); // добавляем результат в массив

    // a bit optimization due to sorting
    if(man2[0]>man1[1])
      break;   
  } 
}

// сортировать manCross не нужно - всё и так красиво :)
console.log(manCross);
```

Comment: А как сравнивать попроще какого нибудь метода нету?

Comment: сравнивать несложно, но слегка громоздко. Я в яве не силен, могу на javascript накидать решение.

Comment: если несложно, то пожалуйста

Comment: можно сортировку не проводить, но тогда убрать // a bit optimization due to sorting

Comment: Если промежутков по 10 - решение сойдет, если по 100 - лучше искать другое

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я уже сам написал. Но за идею спасибо.

Comment: Есть косяк с сортировкой.. счас сиправлю)

Comment: Я бы скинул свой вариант, да не умещается